# Django Add CSS to InlineFormSet

Tags: python, css, django, inline-formset

I am trying to add some CSS data to an inline formset I created. I have done it before to regular `ModelForms` but it is not working for the inline formset.

Here is the custom `__init__`:

```
class CustomSubIFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSubIFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.forms.widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'User Name'})

        for name, forms in self.forms.items():
            forms.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

The call in `views.py`

```
subIFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Study, SubInvestigator, fields=('name',), extra=4, formset=CustomSubIFormset)
```

The error message is `'list'` object has no attribute `'widget'`. Traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/RickyD/PycharmProjects/StudyTrack/studies/views.py" in create_study
  63.         formset = subIFormSet(instance=Study())
File "/Users/RickyD/PycharmProjects/StudyTrack/studies/forms.py" in __init__
  56.         self.forms.widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'User Name'})

Exception Type: AttributeError at /studies/create-study/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'widget'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for form in self.forms:
   for field in form.fields:
      field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems like the issue is the `widget` attribute. Now it says that `str` object has no attribute `widget`.

Comment: actually looks like it works it you change `field.widget.attrs...` to `form.fields[field].attrs...` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**The correct answer is:**

if your get me correct. don't forget to upvote.

```
class InlineFormSet(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            for name in form.fields:
                form.fields[name].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```